# Problem with biblatex: Doesn't compile. I cannot specify

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm having trouble with getting my bibliography running. I don't really know what is going on. For my bib file I don't use the typical biblatex command but a bibtex command instead. I think this shouldn't be an issue. I don't know what most of the error message means. I hope you can help me solve this.

When I run the code, it simply prints my personal citation references and not in the style I want. It also doesn't print the bibliography then.

Output looks like this:
[image]

This is the code I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, natbib, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usepackage{xurl} % handle line breaks in long URL strings gracefully
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional => to make links within document.

\begin{document}

This is a test sentence \citep{test} and the test goes on \cite{test}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
    Process started

    INFO - This is Biber 2.14 
    INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg' 
    INFO - Reading 'test.bcf' INFO - 
    Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0 
    INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Globbing data 
    source 'bib.bib' 
    INFO - Globbed data source 'bib.bib' to bib.bib 
    INFO - Looking for 
    bibtex format file 'bib.bib' for section 0 
    INFO - LaTeX decoding ... 
    INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'bib.bib' 
    ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: 
    /var/folders/n8/lq_mhv5s23z1nwc4gl_gtmw00000gn/T/biber_tmp_Ko2i/bib.bib_44837.utf8, line 
    13, syntax error: found "gyourko", expected "," INFO - ERRORS: 1

    Process exited with error(s)
```

This is what the bibliography looks like:

```
@article{glaeser_gyourko,
Author = {Glaeser, Edward and Gyourko, Joseph},
Title = {The Economic Implications of Housing Supply},
Journal = {Journal of Economic Perspectives},
Volume = {32},
Number = {1},
Year = {2018},
Month = {2},
Pages = {3-30},
DOI = {10.1257/jep.32.1.3},
URL = {https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jep.32.1.3}}

@article{test,
author = {test},
title = {test},
journaltitle = {test},
year = {1234},
OPTurldate = {date url}}
```

I use texmaker on MacOS and for compiling biblatex I use the following command:
[image]

To recompile everything I use the following quick build setup:
[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: are you sure that you have (only) an underscore in `glaeser_gyourko`? The error would happen if there were a space or some other char biber doesn't like.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your answer. I checked and was sure but I think I found the mistake. I believe that it ran into an error because I didn't save properly my bib.bib. I found out that the Asterix next to the document name means that the current version is not saved (for Texmaker that is). This also means that maybe the older version of the bib.bib that biber was working with didn't separate gyourko properly. Does that sound reasonable to you? Another question. I'm new to StackExchange. I have more biblatex questions. I should ask then in different questions, right?

Comment: Yes, please ask new questions as new questions. I think we should vote to close this question here since it turns out that the code shown in the question does not actually reproduce the problem and you managed to solve your question. (So the question as it stands now is unlikely to help future visitors with a similar problem.)

Comment: @moewe, thanks for heads up on StackExchange culture. By all means, please vote to close as I think I can't do it at my level or on my own questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem was resolved by saving the correct version of the `.bib` file. In particular the problem does not occur with the `.bib` file from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

It appears to be case that you have to make sure to save manually the bibliography (.bib file) whenever you change it. That is the case when using Texmaker. That way you may avoid mistakes like these.